# Create Autofill form with PHP

Tags: php, html

So im still relatively new to php and im trying to create a form that autofill's with information from a table. The table is called students and has the students id, first and last name, and their address. Im trying to make it so it only autofill's with the information of the student with a certain id, for example if the students id is 102 it fills the textboxes with their info.

I have some code which i thought would work but its telling me somethings wrong with the while loop and i don't know what.

Edit: The error i keep getting is this:"mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result".

PHP code:

```
<?php
        
require_once ('Connection.php');

$query = "SELECT * from students where Id = 102";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $row['student_id'];
 $row['stu_Fname'];
 $row['stu_Lname'];
 $row['stu_addr'];

}               
?>
```

Html Form:

```
<form action="http://localhost/test.php" method="post">
        
        <p>Student ID:
            <input name="stu_id" size="5" value="<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>" pattern="^\d{3}" required autofocus /><?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>
        </p>
        
        <p>First Name:
            <input type="text" name="fname" size="30" value="<?php echo $row['stu_Fname']; ?>"/>
        </p> 
            
        <p>Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="lname" size="30" value="<?php echo $row['stu_Lname']; ?>"/>
        </p>
        
        <p>Address:
            <input type="text" name="address" size="30" value="<?php echo $row['stu_addr']; ?>"/>
        </p>
        
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>
        </p>
    </form>
```

EDIT: Connection code:

```
<?php
        
        DEFINE ('DB_User', 'testuser');
        DEFINE ('DB_Password', 'abc123*');
        DEFINE ('DB_Host', 'localhost');
        DEFINE ('DB_Name', 'student');          
        
        //start database connection
        $dbc = new mysqli(DB_Host, DB_User,DB_Password,DB_Name);
            
            if(mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                printf("can't connect to database.", mysqli_connect_error());
                exit();
            }           
    ?>
```

Comment: also, add codes from the ``Connection.php`` file. Or confirm what does ``$dbc`` hold?

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $row['student_id'];
 $row['stu_Fname'];
 $row['stu_Lname'];
 $row['stu_addr'];
}
```

You're not actually accomplishing anything within the while loop above. There is no assignment, nor output.

Each iteration of the while loop will grab a row (if there is one in the database). Assuming that the row has the four columns you've listed, you can print the data to the screen. For example:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['student_id'] . ", ";
  echo $row['stu_Fname'] . ", ";
  echo $row['stu_Lname'] . ", ";
  echo $row['stu_addr'];
}
```

Assuming you're outputting a form for each student, you can place the form logic within the while loop.

Comment: I expected not having echos there would cause a problem. But the error im getting says "mysqli_fetch_assoc is expecting parameter 1 to be mysqli_result". what does that mean?

Comment: The usual workflow for database queries is write query, run query, process results. You haven't shown the code for your query setup or query invocation. The second step will provide you an result object that you can pass into mysqli_fetch_assoc, which will then return rows of data (if there are any).

Comment: By query setup and query invocation, what do you mean? Is it the mysqli_query?

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query); : Looks right to me. Check what $result has after that query is run. If the connection is okay and the query valid, then I would expect $result is a mysqli_result object and not give the error you got. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php about the different values that can be returned by mysqli_query.